# Get most ordered products based on orders

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in C# and currently writing (and parallelly learning) API. I've tried to figure out the problem on my own but unsuccessfully. I'd be glad for any advice.
I have a **Order** table

```
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

and a **Product** table

```
 {
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string? ImageURL { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }
}
```

Each **Order** contains only one product, its price and name. When I send to my
**GetProductListQuery**

```
name: null, filter: "FavoriteOrders"
```

I need to lookup for orders, where is for example

```
{OrderId: 1, Name: "Juice", Price: 5, ProductId: 1, UserId: 1}
{OrderId: 2, Name: "Juice", Price: 5, ProductId: 1, UserId: 1}
{OrderId: 3, Name: "Juice", Price: 5, ProductId: 1, UserId: 1}
{OrderId: 4, Name: "Snickers", Price: 3, ProductId: 2, UserId: 1}
{OrderId: 5, Name: "Snickers", Price: 3, ProductId: 2, UserId: 1}
{OrderId: 6, Name: "Water", Price: 1, ProductId: 3, UserId: 1}
```

and output with products should be (simplified): Juice, Snickers, Water, ..all other products, which have zero orders.

My functions right now look like this:

```
 var orders = await _dataContext
            .Entities<Order>()
            .Where(x => x.UserId == 1)
            .GroupBy(o => o.ProductId)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
            .Select(x => x.Key)
            .ToListAsync();

var products = await _dataContext
            .Entities<Product>()
            .OrderByDescending(x => orders.Contains(x.ProductID))
            .ProjectTo<ProductDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .ToListAsync();
```

This code works partly - at the beginning of the ProductList are products that have been ordered, followed by products that have not been ordered, but I need the ordered products to be in the right order (like desired output above - based on the count of their orders). I've tried to edit .OrderByDescending  to

```
.OrderBy(x => orders.IndexOf(x.ProducId)
```

but this code doesn't work. Please can you give me some advices how to solve this problem? I've been looking for a solution 5 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try changing orders.Contains(x.ProductID) to use Count() like this:

```
var products = await _dataContext
            .Entities<Product>()
            .OrderByDescending(x => orders.Count(o => o.ProductID == x.ProductID))
            .ProjectTo<ProductDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .ToListAsync();
```

This is probably not the best performance you can get. For that I would suggest playing around with a [linq query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations) joining orders and products.